# Replace SRC and HREF attributes using regex in PHPStorm

Tags: html, laravel, phpstorm

i am new to laravel and i just got this html template i am converting to a blade template in my application.  However i would like to replace the src and href attributes of all the links and images on the page with the laravel assets function.
eg.

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

Unfortunately there are so many of these in my template that i was wondering if there was a way to just do this with regular expressions using the replace tool in my editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Go Edit->Find->Replace.. , check Regex

In the first row you should enter:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="(.+)"></script>
```

In the second row:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('$1') }}"></script>
```

With images you can do it similarly.

Answer (score 2):

In PhpStorm 10 (it should be similar in other versions) :

Go to : Preferences -> Editor -> Live Templates

1. Click on the Twig section, then click on the + button on the right
2. Choose Live Template
3. in the window that appears

   - choose an abbreviation that you want to assign to the live template
   - add a description of your choice
   - in the template text add this `{{ asset('$SELECTION$') }}`
   - underneath you need to change "Applicable in" and select HTML and Twig.

Now whenever you want to turn a link text into a twig asset in Symfony2, press `Cmd + Alt + T` (on Mac) , `Ctrl + Alt + T` (on Windows). The "Surround With options" dialog box will be displayed, and you can choose the live template you just created and it will do the job.